# prepend profile username to the window title in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to launch chrome in two or three different profiles, one chrome will be launched as user1, another as user2, and the third as user3.

But I want to know, from the windows 7 taskbar, which one is user1, which one is user2, and which one is user3. I can see the title of the active tab in the taskbar, but not which profile the chrome instance is. Is there a way to prepend an abbreviation like U1-  to the title for the chrome of user1?

Comment: nowadays with chrome you can add users, rather than use different profiles. And when you add users you can set an icon, that appears in the top left of the window and identifies each window

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have a mechanism for knowing which user is active on a give Chrome window you could prepend the username to the title in your content-script as follows:

```
var username = 'U1' //I'm assuming you already have this in a variable
document.title = username + ' - ' + document.title;
```

Comment: I haven't developed chrome before.  As for which user is active on a given chrome window. One window(with all its tabs), only has one user because it's launched in a particular profile.